# C++ Dynamically load arbitrary function from DLL into std::function

Tags: c++, dll, c++11, dllexport, std-function

How can I load an arbitrary *dynamic-link library* (dll) function into a `std::function` object using a single function?

For example I would like to compile two functions into a dll:

```
// test.dll

int plusFive(int value) {
    return value + 5;
}

void printHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

And load them both at runtime using a single function like this:

```
// main.cc

#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::function<int(int)> func1(loadDllFunc("test.dll", "plusFive"));
    std::function<void()> func2(loadDllFunc("test.dll", "printHello"));
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the *WinAPI* functions provided in `windows.h` (descriptions taken from [MSDN Dev Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682599(v=vs.85).aspx)).

- `LoadLibrary` - Loads the specified module into the address space of the calling process. Returns a handle to the module.
- `GetProcAddress` - Retrieves the address of an exported function or variable from the specified dynamic-link library (DLL). Returns the address of the exported function or variable.

Use this function to load a specific function and return a `std::function` object:

```
// main.cc

#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <functional>
#include <windows.h>

template <typename T>
std::function<T> loadDllFunc(const std::string& dllName, const std::string& funcName) {
    // Load DLL.
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(dllName.c_str());

    // Check if DLL is loaded.
    if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not load DLL \"" << dllName << "\"" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Locate function in DLL.
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, funcName.c_str());

    // Check if function was located.
    if (!lpfnGetProcessID) {
        std::cerr << "Could not locate the function \"" << funcName << "\" in DLL\"" << dllName << "\"" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create function object from function pointer.
    std::function<T> func(reinterpret_cast<__stdcall T*>(lpfnGetProcessID));

    return func;
}
```

The DLL source should be written like this:

```
// test.cc (test.dll)
#include <iostream>

// Declare function prototypes with "extern C" to prevent name mangling.
// Declare functions using __declspec(dllexport) to signify the intent to export.
extern "C" {
    __declspec(dllexport) int __stdcall plusFive(int);
    __declspec(dllexport) void __stdcall printHello();
}

int plusFive(int value) {
    return value + 5;
}

void printHello() {
    std::cout << "Hello!" << std::endl;
}
```

And then use `loadDllFunc` like this:

```
// main.cc

int main() {
    auto func1 = loadDllFunc<int(int)>("test.dll", "plusFive");
    auto func2 = loadDllFunc<void()>("test.dll", "printHello");

    std::cout << "Result of func1: " << func1(1) << std::endl;
    func2();
}
```

Output:

```
Result of func1: 6
Hello!
```

As a sidenote the DLL can be compiled using GCC (4.7.2) like this:

```
g++ -shared -o test.dll test.cc -std=c++11
```

### Edit:

I'm not sure that the cast in `loadDllFunc` gives the correct type:

```
std::function<T> func(reinterpret_cast<__stdcall T*>(lpfnGetProcessID));
```

It seems to cast it to `__stdcall int (*)(int)` when it should be `int (__stdcall *)(int)`.

Here is another way to implement `loadDllFunc` using an auxiliary parser class. This solution will correctly cast the function pointer to `int (__stdcall *)(int)`.

```
template <typename T>
struct TypeParser {};

template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct TypeParser<Ret(Args...)> {
    static std::function<Ret(Args...)> createFunction(const FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID) {
        return std::function<Ret(Args...)>(reinterpret_cast<Ret (__stdcall *)(Args...)>(lpfnGetProcessID));
    }
};

template <typename T>
std::function<T> loadDllFunc(const std::string& dllName, const std::string& funcName) {
    // Load DLL.
    HINSTANCE hGetProcIDDLL = LoadLibrary(dllName.c_str());

    // Check if DLL is loaded.
    if (hGetProcIDDLL == NULL) {
        std::cerr << "Could not load DLL \"" << dllName << "\"" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Locate function in DLL.
    FARPROC lpfnGetProcessID = GetProcAddress(hGetProcIDDLL, funcName.c_str());

    // Check if function was located.
    if (!lpfnGetProcessID) {
        std::cerr << "Could not locate the function \"" << funcName << "\" in DLL\"" << dllName << "\"" << std::endl;
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    // Create function object from function pointer.
    return TypeParser<T>::createFunction(lpfnGetProcessID);
}
```

Comment: You forgot to `FreeLibrary` when you're done with the function pointer.

Comment: @beerboy Actually at first I included a call to `FreeLibrary` at the end of `loadDllFunc`, just before returning the `std::function`. This worked and the returned function was valid even though the DLL was unloaded. I don't know why it worked, but to be sure I removed the call to `FreeLibrary`. Also, according to the post in this [link](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?168908-Is-it-a-Bad-Practice%99-to-omit-FreeLibrary()), it might not be necessary to call `FreeLibrary` as the DLL should unload automatically upon exit.

Comment: Also there's a bug where the calling convention of the functions in the DLL are defined as `__stdcall`, but they aren't defined as such when they are imported in main.cc.

Comment: Edit: sorry, the __stdcall bug isn't in main.cc, and actually can't be fixed there - the problem is the reinterpret_cast in loadDllFunc: `reinterpret_cast<T*>(lpfnGetProcessID);` casts a `FARPROC` to a function pointer `R(*)(..)` rather than `R(__stdcall *)(..)`.

Comment: @beerboy Didn't see that. I edited the `reinterpret_cast` to include the correct calling convention. I think this fixes the problem. Thanks!

Comment: I couldn't compile your edited version on Visual Studio 2010. 
I got about 29 syntax error. any help would be appreciated? can you post complete code?

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Did you make sure to include the necessary headers? You need `<iostream>`, `<string>`, `<functional>` & `<windows.h>` at least.

Comment: @PriteshAcharya Also I don't know if VS2010 has enough C++11 support. Try a different more up to date compiler if you still get compilation errors (and enable the C++11 flags e.g. in **g++-4.8**: `-std=c++11`).

Comment: @Snps Can you explain how this part of the code works? 
`template <typename T>
struct TypeParser {};
template <typename Ret, typename... Args>
struct TypeParser<Ret(Args...)> {
  ...`

**How typename T gets split into Ret and Args?**